# Count the Number of Characters in a Full FIle Path?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I need to be able to count the number of characters in a full path to a file in windows.   How I am currently accomplishing this task is as follows:

1. Open a command prompt
2. cd to the directory in question (for example c:\CruiseControl\ProjectArtifacts\ProjectName)
3. type the following command
   **dir /s /b > output.csv**
4. Open the resulting output.csv file in excel.
5. use the **=LEN()** function in excel to count the number of characters per row as listed in the output.csv file.

Does anyone know of an explorer shell extension, or some 3rd party tool that could preform this function without me having to manipulate the output from dir in excel?   Is there some easier way to go about doing this?   The root of the issue I am having is the ~260 character file path limit in Windows.  I am trying to analyze which paths are approx ~260 characters so I can shorten them to avoid getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing is very easy to do with [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/cshell.htm).  If this a one-time thing, you'll be happy with the [free version](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Demo.htm).  Here's an example generating the fullpaths of several files in the `c:\Windows` directory, then computing the string lengths.  Full disclosure:  I'm the author.

```
128 C% cd
c:\Windows
129 C% ls mi*
Microsoft.NET      Minidump           mib.bin
130 C% foreach i ( mi* )
131 C? @ f = fullpath ( i )
132 C? echo $i $f $strlen(f)
133 C? end
mib.bin c:\Windows\mib.bin 18
Microsoft.NET c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET 24
Minidump c:\Windows\Minidump 19
134 C%
```

Comment: Nicole - Very impressive btw!  This is exactly what I needed.   I will add a reminder to my calendar to buy a full copy when my next check arrives.

Comment: FYI I went ahead and purchased the Hamilton C Shell.   I will be sure to let people know about this great product!

Comment: Nicole - how would I recurse into sub directories and also list the total path length of files in each directory?   Your example works well for listing the number of characters in the directories, but not the files in each directory.

Comment: As discussed offline, one very easy way to treewalk an entire directory is with the `...` wildcard, e.g., `foreach i (...\*) echo $i; end`.  The `...` construct means "0 or more directory levels, whatever it takes to make the rest of the pattern match."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these simple batch files will come in handy.

1) Counting the number of characters in the current directory:

```
@echo off
echo %cd%>"%TMP%\Temp.txt"
for %%l in ("%TMP%\Temp.txt") do set /a len=%%~zl
del "%TMP%\Temp.txt"
set /a len-=2
echo Path length = %len% chars.
```

`cd` to the dir. and just call the batch file.

2) Counting the number of characters in the specified directory:

```
@echo off
echo %1>"%TMP%\Temp.txt"
for %%l in ("%TMP%\Temp.txt") do set /a len=%%~zl
del "%TMP%\Temp.txt"
set /a len-=4
echo Path length = %len% chars.
```

Call the batch file and pass the full path as an argument to it (be sure to use quotes if the path contains spaces). Note that no error checking is done, so leaving out quotes when the path contains spaces will give an incorrect (low) count, and adding extra backslashes at the end will increase the count.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but it addresses your problem.  Type

```
dir /s /b | findstr -r ...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

In my illustration above, I have typed 255 periods; this will do the `dir /s /b`, which you already know, and show only the lines (file pathnames) that are at least 255 characters long.  Adjust the number of periods to your liking.  Naturally, you can redirect the output of the above to a file for printing or other analysis.